# Trouble understanding recursion in lines dividing a plane.

Tags: recursion

> In how many maximum regions does $n$ lines divide a plane into?

---

It has a well-known recursive formula: $a_{n+1}=a_n+n+1$, where $a_n$ is the number of regions that $n$ lines divide a plane into. I am having a bit trouble understanding the logic behind it. I get that the $n+1^{\text{th}}$ line intersects the previous $n$ lines at $n$ points and everytime it intersects, it creates a new region, so we add $n$. I am having trouble understanding why we add $1$ at the end. What is that extra region?

Comment: Well, why not analyze the case $n=1$ carefully?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an image I provided to [OEIS A000124](https://oeis.org/A000124) (the Lazy Caterer's sequence):

[image: https://oeis.org/A000124]

Consider adding the third cut (so going from $4$ regions to $7$).  It splits

- the region above the intersection with the first cut
- the region between the intersections with the first and second cuts
- the region below the intersection with the second cut

so the third cut adds (up to) $3$ regions, and similarly with the earlier and later other cuts, demonstrating why $$a_{n+1}=a_n+(n+1).$$